# prevent ShareActionProvider from writing to share history file

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, shareactionprovider

I want to prevent ShareActionProvider from writing to any history file. I tried to find which callback function is called on selecting a share app from share menu, but found no callback methods. I want to find which callback method does the job of updating the share history file. This will help me override the method and change the behavior.

Comment: a good place to start researching would be the source, did you try it? https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/ShareActionProvider.java

Comment: Yes. I extended the ShareActionProvider class and overrided all the methods (with logger in each method). Many of the methods are called first time when the view is created. But upon selecting a menu item, none of the methods are called and view gets updated.

Comment: I didn't dig into the code myself, but it's likely it's a private or protected method, so you can't override, but maybe instead of extend it you can copy the whole code and modify to your needs ;)

Comment: I am using Eclipse as IDE. I have added android-17 sources to adt-bundle-windows-x86/sdk/sources/android-17. I am able to view the source code of android.widgets.ShareActionProvider.java. However I am not able to view ActivityChooserView.java and ActivityChooserModel.java. These classes are responsible to maintaining the share history and are used inside ShareActionProvider.java. Any idea where to find these. Thats why when i copied ShareActionProvider.java to my eclipse project, there are many java import resolve issues. The java compiler is not able to find these classes.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like after our comments you could answer your own question, but you didn't so here goes:

you have two options, and those are based on the conclusion that, you will not be able to directly override something to avoid the history, so:

1) here are the links with all the original classes and you copy those to your project and built a NoHistoryShareActionProvider. [ShareActionProvider](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/widget/ShareActionProvider.java?av=f), [ActivityChooserView](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/widget/ActivityChooserView.java?av=f), [ActivityChooserModel](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/widget/ActivityChooserModel.java?av=f) and further around on GrepCode you can find any other necessary classes.

2) step one class back, and create a subclass from [ActionProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionProvider.html) mimicking the appearance of the ShareActionProvider sans the history.

I agree that both are long and solutions and would be great to have a simple config where to decide to have it or not, but that's how it is.

happy coding!